# Unable to bind mount in Arch linux

Tags: bind-mount

I tried the following:

`sudo mount --bind /dev/sda1 /path/to/a/directory`
 `sudo mount -o bind /Dec/sda1 /path/to/a/directory`

both gives an error message :

`mount(2): system call failed: Not a directory`

However, if I remove be `bind`option , I can mount it.
So I did a generic mount  and put `ntfs-3g` (because it's n NTFS drive ) under filesystem `bind` under option in `fstab`.
will this be a bind mount ? Also, How do i check whether it is bind mounted or not ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the bind mount? Bind mounts are for mounting one directory to another, not a device.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I want to bind mount the NTFS drive as a shared storage between my windows and Linux system. It is a dual boot.

Comment: Then you don't need to use the bind option. Look at the man page for mount - what you're trying to do does not require bind.

Comment: To clarify: `/dev/sda1` is a special *file* and you can bind mount it over another (e.g. regular) file. The other file will then appear as a special file and behave like `/dev/sda1`; it would be like `/dev/sda1` under a different path. This won't give you access to the filesystem; usual (non-bind) mount does this. After you mount the filesystem in a usual way, you can bind mount its mountpoint (which is a directory) over another directory. Is this what you want? Why do you think you need "bind" in the first place?